# Can't do the for loop with Alpine js and dynamically show item's title

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, store, alpine.js

I wonder why I can't do the for loop with Alpine js and dynamically show item's title. I'm trying to use store inside the script html tag and to loop over an array of objects , and get the title key of the object.

```js
// html

<div class="content__mid"  x-for="item in $store.products.items" :key="item.id">
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.title"></p> // the sontent is empty here
</div>

<script>
      document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.store('products', {
        items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Aspirin',
            country: 'USA',
            manufacturer: 'Bangladesh',
            price: '120',
            validDate: '02.10.2024'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Aspirin',
            country: 'Italy',
            manufacturer: 'Bangladesh',
            price: '120',
            validDate: '02.10.2024'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Aspirin',
            country: 'Austria',
            manufacturer: 'Bangladesh',
            price: '140',
            validDate: '02.10.2024'
          }
        ],
      })
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`x-for` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for) must be declared on a `<template>` element:

```
<div class="content__mid" x-data="">
  <template x-for="item in $store.products.items" :key="item.id">
    <p class="content__mid-item" x-text="item.title"></p>
  </template>
</div>
```

Note: I've also added an empty `x-data` directive that is required for each Alpine.js component. Remove it if any parent element already contains it.